# Is Records Management An Enterprise Feature?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, records-management, records-center

How do I find out which features are Enterprise and which are standard?

For example, is Records Management an enterprise feature requiring an Enterprise CAL?  Also is a Document Center an enterprise feature requiring and enterprise CAL?

As a further example that outlines lack of clarity on licensing there are the following three separate features:

1. RecordResources
2. RecordsCenter
3. RecordsManagement
4. ContentOrganizer

These have separate GUID's in the solution feature store.  For licensing purposes, how do I know which of these are Enterprise?

Answer (score 1):

here you can check feature comparison.

http://www.fpweb.net/sharepoint-2013/compare-sharepoint-server-standard-enterprise/

Rm is the standard features but if you want to use `E-discover, ACM, Compliance` then you need the enterprise Cal for each user.
check these slides will help you http://www.slideshare.net/d501159/sharepoint-2013-licensing-overview-from-atidan

Comment: It's not clear really from that.  For example, the Records Center feature is separate feature with a separate feature GUID so even though Records Management may be a Standard feature does a Records Center require an enterprise CAL?

Comment: All are the standard features.